# after change marker icon infowindow is not display - android googlemap v2

Tags: android, icons, google-maps-android-api-2, marker, infowindow

I want to change the marker Icon at run time to indicate the status of each resource. I can change the icon but after change when I click on the marker, infowindow is not displaying. But I observe when I try continues clicks, info window is displays some times but quickly disappear.

If I don't change the icon everything work fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug related to [the one I reported on gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5419). Current `setIcon` implementation has issues that make it unusable for most cases.

I can only suggest starring that issue and maybe adding a comment and a snippet of code you have problems with.